# LWC ChartJs not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, chartjs

I am building al screen flow-enabled LWC to show a simple line chart (the evolution of a score), but this implementation is unable to pass the data gathered to the chart presentation... (labels and data are shown as "null")...

The goal is to show 3 values: score two weeks ago; score one week ago; score today (so we can see if score is improving or not).

The result is (copied from the flow screen):

[image]

The chart shows 3 values in the X axis (which is correct, I need to show values for 3 different dates) but are null; the values are null too.

BC_puntajeActor (the presentation) JS:

```
import {LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getEstosDatos from '@salesforce/apex/BC_puntajeActor.getEstosDatos';
export default class BC_puntajeActor extends LightningElement {
   @track chartConfiguration;
   @wire(getEstosDatos, {})
   getEstosDatos({error, data}) {
   if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      console.log('error => ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      this.chartConfiguration = undefined;
   } else if (data) {
      let chartData = [];
      let etiquetas = [];
      data.forEach(ptj => {
         chartData.push(ptj.puntaje);
         etiquetas.push(ptj.fecha);
      });

      this.chartConfiguration = {
         type: 'line',
         data: {
            labels: etiquetas,
            datasets: [
               {
                     label:'Puntaje',
                     data: chartData,
                     borderColor:'rgba(62, 159, 222, 1)',
                     borderWidth: 1,
                     fill: false,
                     pointBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
                     pointBorderWidth: 4,
                     pointHoverRadius: 5,
                     pointRadius: 3,
                     bezierCurve: true,
                     pointHitRadius: 10
               }
            ]
         },
      };
      console.log('data => ', data);
      this.error = undefined;
   }
   }
}
```

Chart.js (the config JS):

```
import {LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';
import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/BC_ChartJs';
import {loadScript} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class Chart extends LightningElement {
 @api loaderVariant = 'base';
 @api chartConfig;

 @track isChartJsInitialized;
 renderedCallback() {
  if (this.isChartJsInitialized) {
   return;
  }
  // load static resources.
  Promise.all([loadScript(this, chartjs)])
   .then(() => {
    this.isChartJsInitialized = true;
    //c/chartconst ctx = this.template.querySelector('canvas.lineChart').getContext('2d');
    const ctx = this.template.querySelector('canvas');
    this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.chartConfig)));
   })
   .catch(error => {
    this.dispatchEvent(
     new ShowToastEvent({
      title: 'Error loading ChartJS',
      message: error.message,
      variant: 'error',
     })
    );
   });
 }
}
```

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class BC_puntajeActor {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Data> getEstosDatos(){
        return BC_puntajeActor.obtenerDatosGrafico();
    }
    
    @RemoteAction
    public static List<Data> obtenerDatosRemotos(){
        return BC_puntajeActor.obtenerDatosGrafico();
    }
    
    public static List<Data> obtenerDatosGrafico(){
        List<Data> estosDatos = new List<Data>();
        // the code to query data an create the data list...
        return estosDatos;
    }
    public class Data {
        public Date fecha {get;set;}
        public Double puntaje {get; set;}
        public Data(Date fecha, Double puntaje) {
            this.fecha = fecha;
            this.puntaje = puntaje;
        }
    }
}
```

The chart is **well shown within the screen flow**, but labels and values are ***null***.

When I try hardcoding the values they're shown ok. Here is what I tried (after the data.foreach):

```
// these are shown ok in the chart so
// I presume the problem is not in the chart
// but when passing the data from the class to the JS
chartData.push(10);
etiquetas.push('2023-09-01');
```

I'm lost... any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thx

EDIT

Comment: It actually brings all three records (date, score; date, score; date, score) but these data appear "undefined" and the chart is empty (null everywhere!)

Comment: You need to narrow down your problem. As is stands, it's really hard to understand. "when i try hardcoded values" doesn't help.  Hardcoded what? where? As it stands, this question is likely to be closed because it's too broad.  Please edit your question and identify exactly where the problem in your code is.  If you don't know where the problem is, you need to spend some time understanding your code and work out which line isn't doing what you want.

Comment: Sorry, Nick. I should've been more precise. I'm trying to draw a line chart with 3 values: score 2 weeks ago, score last week, score today. So far I only get 3 "undefined" values in both arrays (chartData and etiquetas (labels)). I tried pushing hardcoded values (to test if it works) into the arrays and I do get a chart, so narrowing down the problem it seems I am unable to get the values from the class into the "data" (or the arrays) and that's why they are null (even tho I get arrays of 3 values each).

Comment: As for the "hardcoded" I did this:  chartData.push(200); etiquetas.push('2023-09-11'); and the chart actually draws it (I guess the problem seems to be  passing the values from the class into the js).

Comment: What does a `fecha` Date look like?  Is it the same format as '2023-09-11'? Have you tried debugging the values of `chartData` and `etiquetas`? Do they have the values you expect in them?

Comment: When I debug the apex class: 08:11:13:029 USER_DEBUG [46]|DEBUG (Data:[fecha=2023-08-31 00:00:00, puntaje=49.0], Data:[fecha=2023-09-07 00:00:00, puntaje=49.0], Data:[fecha=2023-09-14 00:00:00, puntaje=49.0]). I don't really know how to debug in the page (to know what values are in fecha and puntaje). BTW fecha = date and puntaje = score...

Comment: Found it! data =>  Array(3)0: {}1: {}2: {}length: 3[[Prototype]]: Array(0) It's clearly empty (but the class does create the List<Data>)...